# CSS3 rotate or Border - issues

Tags: html, css, rotation, border, transform

I'm trying to do this :
[image: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/743/UPF58W.jpg]

Let me explain :
- Black color is my background
- Grey block is my png logo
- blue / red are 2 div

for the moment i have this (browser resolution : 1920x927px) and it's perfect, but I don't manage to adapt/find the solution to the other resolution :

```
    <div class="l-content"></div>
    <div class="l-content2"></div>

    <style>
        .l-content{
            position: absolute;
            border-bottom:960px solid red;
            border-left:0px solid transparent;
            border-right:550px solid transparent;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 0;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity:0.5;
        }
        .l-content2{
            position: absolute;
            border-bottom:960px solid blue;
            border-right:0px solid transparent;
            border-left:550px solid transparent;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 0;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            opacity:0.5;
        }
    </style>
```

I tried with transform rotate, but I didn't find the good way...

So, it work on my resolution, but I want to do it flexible for all resolution...
Do you have any ideas ? solutions ?

Here's an example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jfqIe if i reduce wrapper width and/or height, everything is broken...

Thx

Comment: any ideas to do what?

Comment: This is what I can see from your code: http://jsbin.com/govaq/1/edit (so far)

Comment: Border is a super great idea if you want it cross-browser. Rotate... well only if you don't have any content inside (that you would counter-rotate to make it straight). SVG if you want to amaze your desk colleague.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : that's the problem... I manage to have the good result on my resolution (1920x927) but it's not ok on the others..

Comment: ok, but I cannot see any *black*, any logo, anything in your demo, just a purple background and a red and blue *inclined* sides. You did not specified (beside your extra small image) how you're expecting it to be. afaics size matters. Or? Should it be responsive? .... too many questions.

Comment: Here's an example :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jfqIe

if i reduce wrapper width and/or height, everything is broken...